# Eclipse dark theme broken with .groovy?

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

This is how it looks like when opening .groovy files.
This is the default dark theme in Eclipse.
My version of Eclipse is Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2).

[image]

Why are the brackets and commas black for example? I cannot imagine that it is supposed to look like that, it's just ugly and unreadable, especially with this pink stuff. Java files are ok though.
I also tried the Eclipse Color Theme plugin, but the brackets and commas are still black with other "dark" themes.

Is there something wrong with my Eclipse?

Comment: It seems the Groovy plug-in does not support the Dark Theme. In _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_ you can adapt it manually. Consider contributing back your settings to the Groovy plug-in team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution which I'm satisfied with.
Thanks to [howlger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567437/eclipse-dark-theme-broken-with-groovy#comment84131235_48567437), I randomly saw that there is a "Copy Java Color Preferences" button at the very bottom.
[image]

Result:

[image]

I hope that might help others in future who are also struggling to find a satisfying solution.